# How D3 key function in data binding works

Tags: javascript, d3.js

All:

**[UPDATE]**

> Finally figure out how D3 key function works conceptually: when using
>   .data(newdata, key_function), this function will extract old bined
>   data from element and put it into this key function get a key, and do
>   same thing with the newdata, and compare them, if same, replace the
>   old data with new data. **important thing(to me)** here is: the key(
>   for old data and new data) is always generated by current
>   key_function, so once we change key function, and if we still want to
>   bind data to original element, we need find a way to make sure the key
>   can be consistent.
>
> The official explain is here(according to Cool Blue): https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data

I am new to D3 data binding, after reading http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/   , there is still one question about how D3 key function works:

I am wondering if each round of data update is independent or it relates to the key specified by previous round data binding?(how the key stored: is it stored in element as attribute? will it be deleted if no key function specified later)

Like

**1st round data binding:**

```
var letters = [
  {name: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {name: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {name: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {name: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {name: "E", frequency: .12702}
];

function name(d) {
  return d.name;
};

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var divs = d3.selectAll("div")
             .data(letters, name);
divs.enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("width", 50)
    .style("height", function(d, i){
        return d.frequency*500+"px";
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d, i){
        return color(i);
    });
```

**then sort data and bind again:**

```
    letters.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.frequency - b.frequency;
    });
```

**[1] with key function binding:**

```
    divs.data(letters, name)
        .transition()
        .style("background-color", function(d, i){
            return color(i);
        })
        .style("height", function(d, i){
            return d.frequency*3000+"px";
        });
```

**OR
[2] without key function binding:**

```
    divs.data(letters)
        .transition()
        .style("background-color", function(d, i){
            return color(i);
        })
        .style("height", function(d, i){
            return d.frequency*3000+"px";
        });
```

Could any one give me some explanation what happened to these 2 different data  binding? My main confuse is if I did not specify the key function in data updating, will the old key binded to that element be removed and then based on index until another key function is specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key function doesn't change the underlying data, it just tells D3 how to extract the identifying attribute -- each datum (in the data passed to `.data()` and bound to the DOM elements) will be passed into the key function, the return value will be used to match up elements (i.e. those for which the same value is returned for both DOM element and datum).

If you change key functions when updating, the computed selections will change accordingly. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, so the way D3 matching new data with element(conceptually) is using key function generate key for current new data( let it be "mykey") and loop through all elements and extract the key bind to them(let it be "bindkey") and compare mykey with bindkey, if same, replace the data with current new data? If my understanding is correct, then there should be somewhere to store the key in element, how can I access them?

Comment: I think "mykey" and "bindkey" are the same in what you're saying -- the key function tells D3 what part of the data is the key to use to match. There's really no difference between the data and key as in that the key is part of the data. (Ok technically it doesn't have to be but let's assume it is here to make things easier.)

Comment: I feel my understanding stuck at how D3 use the key function. My understanding is the key function only apply to current new data to get the key, and find the old key in the element, is that right?

Comment: No, as I wrote in the answer, every element in the first argument to `.data()` and the data bound to the elements selected before is passed to the key function. The return value is used to do the matching.

Comment: So you mean each compare we call key function twice?

Comment: Thanks Lars, I finally got it! The place I got stuck is: I thought the element saves the old key for future comparation. But actually, D3 generate a new key by using new key function.

Comment: Yes, the "key" is ephemeral in that it's not saved anywhere -- it only exists as a separate entity when the selections are computed.

Comment: so if we change the key function, sometimes, matching same key could be a problem.....

Comment: If you change the key function you could get a completely different matching, i.e. completely different enter/update/exit selections.

Comment: @Kuan yes, the key function is called twice during the binding process, each time with different arguments and different `this` context. I tried to explain it [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) in the section on key function...

Comment: @Kuan if it's not clear let me know... I need to edit it, it's a bit complicated to explain.

Comment: @CoolBlue  Thanks, I guess I got the basic idea,